# Linux Device Driver: Is it possible to pass a char* to unlocked_ioctl?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to pass a char* to unlocked_ioctl without using a struct that contains the size of the char*?

Comment: There is a convention that the ioctl command code encodes the size of the object pointed to by the third argument by setting the `_IOC_SIZEMASK` bits of the command code appropriately, but it is only a convention. There is nothing to prevent drivers ignoring that convention.

Comment: @IanAbbott Great comment.  I remember seeing that referenced somewhere but could not find any more detail

Comment: For example, older subsystems such as TTY do not follow the convention, because they pre-date it!  Well, some of the newer TTY ioctl codes such as `TCGETS2` _do_ follow the convention, but the older ones don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the driver what the parameters are. [KDGETLED](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html) is one that already exists and is documented as taking `char *`. It ends up in [vt_do_kdskled](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c#L2097) where it writes one byte to the address pointed to by the argument.

### Update

`unlocked_ioctl` is the internal implementation of the `ioctl(2)` system call. The manual for ioctl(2) points out:

> The third argument is an untyped pointer to memory.
>          It's traditionally char *argp (from the days before void * was valid C),

So in `unlocked_ioctl` which has the signature `long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);`, the third argument is cast to whatever the driver specifies.

You can see this in the `vt_do_kdskled` example I referenced above where this parameter is case to accept the single byte result on line 2099:

```
int vt_do_kdskled(int console, int cmd, unsigned long arg, int perm)
{
    ....
    case KDGETLED:
        ucval = getledstate();
        return put_user(ucval, (char __user *)arg);
```

This `arg` parameter got here via the ioctl call from [vt_ioctl](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt_ioctl.c#L568). Its just passed along to the implementation.

Comment: I don't understand when you say it is up to the driver what the parameters are.  Is this not the prototype: long my_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy It is up to the driver how the parameters are interpreted. The final unsigned long argument of the unlocked_ioctl file operation handler is often treated as a pointer to something in user-space memory.